# Print text from a terminal command into shell

Tags: python

I am creating a MS-DOS replica to test out my python skills since I am particularly new and I'm writing the "dir" command. Right now, the command opens a terminal that seems to be doing what I want it to be doing, except for printing it out into a terminal instead of the program output. I want to transfer the text it creates in the command line to the output of the program, basically. Here's what I'm using right now:

```
if COMMAND == ("dir"):
    os.system('dir')
```

Anyway, thanks for the help if anyone sees this, since I am pretty nooby at python and new to this website.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `subprocess.check_output`.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> print subprocess.check_output("dir", shell=True)
 Volume in drive C is System
 Volume Serial Number is E4C1-A0AA

 Directory of C:\Users\Kevin

04/30/2015  08:12 AM    <DIR>          .
04/30/2015  08:12 AM    <DIR>          ..
03/30/2015  02:51 PM    <DIR>          Contacts
...
```

Comment: Hi kevin, thanks for answering. I get a syntax error at     subprocess.check_output("dir", shell=True)

Comment: Check the line before that one. You may be missing a parenthesis.

Comment: Here's the main code where I am having problems.    LINE = True
while LINE == True:
    COMMAND = input("C:\>")
    if COMMAND not in MAIN:
        print ("Invalid parameter")
    if COMMAND == ("dir"):
        os.system('dir')
        print subprocess.check_output("dir", shell=True)